# Recruiter Parlance - What is an "Authorable Workflow?"

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, software-development

I found an employer who requires that employees debug "Authorable Workflows." A quick google search reveals that the term is only ever used in job classifieds. Given the way the English language works, an "authorable workflow" is a workflow able to have an author. However, I do not know what it would mean for a workflow have an author.

Comment: Is this for a potential job?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it has an general definition, so you'll have to interpret the phrase literally.

The recruiter will have been given a job spec, then translated it into vague language to stop people finding the employer.

The software is designed to build workflows - perhaps they are talking about a CMS which lets you setup workflows such as edit, review, release and these steps require logic between them.

It may also be some form of workflow management software. A quick search engine query will bring up examples.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for it and found quite a few adverts. In that position, you would be designing work flows that other employees would follow. Or in this case, looking at work flows that have been designed and are used / followed by employees, and figuring out if there is something wrong with those workflows.

It is quite likely that if you don't know exactly what it is then the job is not for you. I have a vague idea what it is, and I think the jobs that I saw are not for me.